# Google chart legends - Overlapping text

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using google chart in my page but the legend text is Overlapped, as the image bellow:

[image]

This is my code:

```js
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn("date", "Data");
dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora");
dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora Equiv.");
dataTable.addColumn("number", "Peso (Ton.)");

for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
  var temp = new Date(dados[i].DT_FIM);

  dataTable.addRow([new Date(temp.getFullYear(), temp.getMonth())
                    ,dados[i].TON_HORA
                    ,dados[i].TON_HORA_EQUIV
                    ,dados[i].PES_LIQUI_UNMET]);
}

var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: "MMM/yyyy"
});

date_formatter.format(dataTable, 0);

var options = {
  hAxis: {title: 'Período (mês/ano)'},
  series: {0: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
           1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
           2: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1 }
          },
  legend: { position: "top", textStyle: { fontSize: 14 } },
  width: 1200,
  height: 500
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("div-Equipamento-Produtividade"));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

My charts is on bootstrap tab nav:

```html
<div id="div-Graficos" class="panel-collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="tab-Graficos" class="nav nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#div-Grafico-OEE" aria-controls="div-Grafico-OEE" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Equipamento - OEE</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#div-Grafico-T2" aria-controls="div-Grafico-T2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Equipamento - T2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#div-Grafico-Produtividade" aria-controls="div-Grafico-Produtividade" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Equipamento - Produtividade</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="div-Grafico-OEE">
        <div id="div-Equipamento-OEE" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="div-Grafico-T2">
        <div id="div-Equipamento-T2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="div-Grafico-Produtividade">
        <div id="div-Equipamento-Produtividade" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the position to "bottom" but the problem continue

What i'm making wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check that the chart is not being drawn while hidden

see the following snippet, the chart is hidden by default,
then shown once the chart's `'ready'` event fires

notice, it produces the same result as posted in the question...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn("date", "Data");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora Equiv.");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Peso (Ton.)");

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var temp = new Date();

      dataTable.addRow([new Date(temp.getFullYear(), i)
                        ,(i + 2) * 6
                        ,(i + 1) * 12
                        ,(i + 0) * 18]);
    }

    var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: "MMM/yyyy"
    });

    date_formatter.format(dataTable, 0);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {title: 'Período (mês/ano)'},
      series: {0: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
               1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
               2: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1 }
              },
      legend: { position: "top", textStyle: { fontSize: 14 } },
      width: 1200,
      height: 500
    };

    var container = document.getElementById("div-Equipamento-Produtividade");
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      container.style.display = null;
    });
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div-Equipamento-Produtividade" style="display: none;"></div>
```

---

however, if the `container` is shown *before* drawing the chart,
the legend turns out nicely...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn("date", "Data");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Ton./Hora Equiv.");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Peso (Ton.)");

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var temp = new Date();

      dataTable.addRow([new Date(temp.getFullYear(), i)
                        ,(i + 2) * 6
                        ,(i + 1) * 12
                        ,(i + 0) * 18]);
    }

    var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: "MMM/yyyy"
    });

    date_formatter.format(dataTable, 0);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {title: 'Período (mês/ano)'},
      series: {0: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
               1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
               2: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1 }
              },
      legend: { position: "top", textStyle: { fontSize: 14 } },
      width: 1200,
      height: 500
    };

    var container = document.getElementById("div-Equipamento-Produtividade");
    container.style.display = null;
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div-Equipamento-Produtividade" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: You're correct. But I can't hide the chart? I will edit my post and add the html code.

Comment: can you wait until the tab is selected to draw the chart?

Comment: Currently the data is returned from an Ajax call, and I fill in all the charts from the same result ... Unless I store the result in session storage ...

Comment: I change my code and i'm drawing the chart when the user click in the specific tabe, but the problem continue... Event: $('.list-group li').click(function(e) {

Comment: once you draw the chart hidden, re-drawing won't help. needs to wait until displayed for first initial draw. -- normally hard-coding the `width` resolves this issue, but not the case here. tried several options to fix but nothing works...

Comment: This just saved the day. Excellent answer !

Comment: I know this is an older answer, but I am hoping you can help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719154/how-to-fix-overlapping-google-chart-legend

Answer (score 1):

Every framework or code that hides the chart DIV using "display: none" will make legends to overlap when the chart is draw inside an inactive DIV.

Hidding the chart DIV with "visibility: hidden" works fine, with no overlapping.

I had this issue and only solved it coding the NAV features by myself, without using Bootstrap/JQuery/etc...