# Section Views displays based on checkbox selection, how to draw Google Charts with good legend?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, hidden

So I have read you can't draw nice Google Charts when the div's are hidden, somehow the legend is way off.

Now I am trying some solutions I have found here, but none of them seems to work. I am using this as last part of my draw Chart function

```
var container = document.getElementById("chart1");
    container.style.display = null;
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    chart.draw(data, options);


    and my Google Chart calls

//  Section1
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawA1);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawA2);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawA3);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawa4);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawA5);
        //Section2
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawB1);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawB2);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawB3);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawB4);
        // Section3
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC1);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC2);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC3);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC4);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC5);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawC6);
```

On page load all sections are hidden and this is the function which show hides section views based on checkboxes selected

```
// Show / Hide Section Views
                $("input[name='section_view[]']:checked").each(function ()
                {
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");

                    $("#section_view" + inputValue).toggle();
                    $("#menuItemSection" + inputValue).toggle();
                });
```

What else can I try so the google charts are drawn as expected???

ps: I am trying out [How to fix overlapping Google Chart legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719154/how-to-fix-overlapping-google-chart-legend) for my situation, but no luck at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `setOnLoadCallback` only needs to be called once per page load
but you can use the promise the `load` statement returns instead
in addition, the `load` statement will wait for the page to load before returning the promise
as such, `google.charts.load` can be used in place of --> `$(document).ready` (or similar method)

recommend replacing *"on page load"* function with `google.charts.load`
move all the page load stuff there

and when the promise is returned, you can start drawing charts without --> `setOnLoadCallback`
when section is made visible, use the toggle's `complete` option to know when `toggle` is done
(just provide a function)

then draw the chart
you can probably use `inputValue` to know which chart to draw
see following example...

```
// replace $(document).ready with the following

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {  // <-- promise function returned

  // move on page load stuff here

  // move draw chart functions here...
  $("input[name='section_view[]']:checked").each(function ()
  {
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      $("#section_view" + inputValue).toggle(function () {

        $("#menuItemSection" + inputValue).toggle(function () {

          // draw chart
          switch (inputValue) {
            case 'A1':
              drawA1();
              break;

            case 'B1':
              drawB1();
              break;

            // etc...
          }

        });

      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you saved my day (after testing it out yesterday, I think your solution is the way to go, now the legend seem to be displayed correctly). Need to make some layout adjustment and add trendlines and a customer marker line, but so far you help me out tremendously.

Comment: I have some kind of followup question: Is there a function which removes the charts? Like a function UndrawB1(): With PHP I am checking if a variable has been set I would like to remove the charts if the variable has not been set...

Comment: yes, there is a chart method for --> `clearChart` -- e.g. -- `chart.clearChart()`