# Angular: loop it's returning me an undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript, google-visualization, angular-google-chart

I'm trying to use Google Charts to draw a chat based on my array of objects.

I get the array, map the values to make a loop in the objects, and insert each value in the chart. But it's not working because the value that's returning for me it's undefined.

I don't know what to do. When I do that on `ngOnInit()` the values it returns for me normally, bus when I put this logic in some function, is not work =(

**component.ts**

```
   declare var google: any;

   @Component({selector, template...})

   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    tableContent!: ProgressTableDatas[];

    constructor(private dropdownService: DropdownService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.tableContent = this.dropdownService.getProgressTableDatas();

     let datas = this.tableContent.map(data => data);

     for (let i = 0; i <= datas.length; i++) {
         console.log(datas[i].region, datas[i].budget, datas[i].closed);

         //Here the values it returns for me normally, like that
         // Region1 0.00 0.00
         // Region2 0.00 0.00...

     }

     google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawColumnChart);
   }

    // Here I get this error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region').'

    drawColumnChart() {
     let datas = this.tableContent.map(data => data);

     for (let i = 1; i <= datas.length; i++) {
       var graphic = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Region', 'Budget', 'Closed'],
         [datas[i].region, datas[i].budget, datas[i].closed]
       ]);
     }

     var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('progressGraphic'));

     chart.draw(graphic);
    }

   }
```

**dropdown.service**

```
getProgressTableDatas() {
    return[
      {
        "region": "Region1",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "region": "Region2",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },      {
        "region": "Region3",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "region": "Region4",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "region": "Region5",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "region": "Region6",
        "budget": "0.00",
        "closed": "0.00"
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I doubt that you are using [tag:angularjs] since that project has been dead since January, 2022.... angularjs !== angular.

Answer (score 1):

arrays in javascript have a zero-based index,
meaning the first index in the array is 0.
and the last index is the length - 1.
if an array has 6 elements, the last index is 5.

here, you're starting at 1 and ending at 6.

```
 for (let i = 1; i <= datas.length; i++) {
```

in this case `datas[6]` is undefined...

you should be starting at 0 and ending at 5.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
```

*** also ***

you only need to call `setOnLoadCallback` once...

```
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();  // <-- remove this
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawColumnChart);
```

*** EDIT ***

from the comment, it sounds like you losing context or reference to `this`
*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tableContent')*

as such, try drawing the chart inside `ngOnInit`, as follows.
note: the values for each series should be a number `0`, not a string `"0.00"`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.tableContent = this.dropdownService.getProgressTableDatas();

  let datas = this.tableContent.map(data => {
    return [data.region, parseFloat(data.budget), parseFloat(data.closed)];
  });

  google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
  }).then(function () {
    var graphic = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datas);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('progressGraphic'));

    chart.draw(graphic);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but not work =(

Now I get this error:

`loader.js:113 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tableContent')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tableContent')`

Comment: it didn't work but I made the chart with the data directly on it. And now I have another problem... The graphic is being shown normally but the subtitles when positioned at the top are overlapping.

I already looked at your answers in other questions with this same theme here in the forum:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719154/how-to-fix-overlapping-google-chart-legend but I couldn't solve it... Could you try to help me with this problem?