# Is there a max. number of Google Charts on one page?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is hunting me the last 1.5 hour. I am trying to add a 16th graphs on a page (from a total of 20th) and now the legends of all graphs are off.

```
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart1);

        //  Incidents
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart2);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart3);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart4);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart5);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart6);
        //Target & Replacement
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart7);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart8);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart9);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart10);
        // Behavior Score
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart11);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart12);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart13);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart14);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart15);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart14a);
```

adding another Chart and I got[image]

the new Chart is a copy of chart 14 to test with, but with his own div id

each div is like so

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <h3 class="columnchartheader">T 14a</h3>
                                    <div id="columnchart">
                                        <div id="t14a"></div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
```

[EDIT] and now all Charts are scaled down??? Should I set a default width for each chart?

[EDIT2] Thanks to WhiteHat I think I now know what the cause is: I have all the Chart section views hidden. After a user makes some data selections and which view section, I am showing the Charts. So data selections boxes and which section to show happens in the same form. Apparently this can't be done???

Comment: any chance the chart container is hidden when the chart is drawn? can cause [legend overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41613032/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat i will double check but it happens to all charts? I might be starring to long to the same issue

Comment: @WhiteHat and now all Charts are scaled down??? Should I set a default width for each chart?

Comment: hard-coding the size of the chart will help, but ultimately, you want to wait until the container is visible, before drawing for the first time

Comment: @WhiteHat.....you might be right about the containers been hidden...... I have used display: none; for each sectionview where a chart is drawn. But sometimes the Legends are drawn correctly. I hope this is the cause... How can i fix this??? 
I am drawing the chart after certain selections have been made??