# Google bar chart layout not right when chart hidden onload

Tags: javascript, css, function, google-visualization, onload

I have created a Google bar chart which displays data from a database. The chart works fine and displays correctly, however if I set a javascript function to hide the div in which the chart is contained on window load, the chart gets hidden but when I press a button to see the chart again, the layout is different and I cannot see the whole chart...

I have css for the chart which specifies size etc and have the display property as block. It looks like the css is being overridden?

Does anyone know how to correct this issue as I have spent a lot of time working on it with no luck...

Comment: only draw the chart when it's container is visible -- see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613423/5090771)...

Comment: @whitehat thank you, it worked for me.