# Hide chart using Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, google-visualization

I am using 8 ColumnCharts populated by a database. Is it possible to hide some of them? When I put the visible to false all the graphs from that stop appearing? Is there a solution?

Comment: it's possible to hide the chart's container with css, as with any element -- just [make sure the container is visible before drawing for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41613032/5090771)...

Comment: The problem is that by hiding the first with css, the second post in the same position and not in the previous position ...