# Why google charts missing legend text while loading second time?

Tags: java, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I'm using ajax to load google charts. whenever a link is clicked, an ajax method is fired which will load google charts(line, pie charts). First time loading, it works fine. But for the second time, legend text seems to be missing from all charts.

code is as shown below:

---

```
function assetReport(assetId) {
         AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){
            A.io.request('<%=reportForAssetURL.toString()%>',
                                    {
                                        method : 'post',
                                        data : {
                                            <portlet:namespace/>id : assetId
                                        },
                                        on : {
                                            success : function() {

                                                console.log(this.get('responseData'));

                                                var json = JSON.parse(this.get('responseData'));

                                                 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                                                  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                                                  function drawChart() {

                                                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                                                    var options = {
                                                            legend:'top',
                                                      title: '',
                                                      'width':500,
                                                         'height':500
                                                    };

                                                   data.addColumn('string', 'word');
                                                        data.addColumn('number', 'count');

                                                        for (var i = 0; i < json.pie.length; i++) {
                                                            data.addRow([json.pie[i].name, json.pie[i].value]);
                                                        }


                                                        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('container1'));
                                                        chart.draw(data, options);  
                                                  }

                                                    /* val= json.guage.value;
                                                    ser = json.guage.name;
                                                    guageChart(val,ser); */

                                                    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
                                                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCrosshairs);

                                                    function drawCrosshairs() {
                                                          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                                          data.addColumn('string', 'X');
                                                          data.addColumn('number', 'usage count');


                                                          for (var i = 0; i < json.line.length; i++) {
                                                                data.addRow([json.line[i].name, json.line[i].value]);
                                                            }


                                                          var options = {
                                                          legend:'top',
                                                            hAxis: {
                                                              title: 'Days',
                                                              slantedTex: 'false'
                                                            },
                                                            vAxis: {
                                                              title: 'Usage Count'
                                                            },
                                                            colors: ['#a52714', '#097138'],
                                                            crosshair: {
                                                              color: '#000',
                                                              trigger: 'selection'
                                                            },
                                                              'width':500,
                                                              'height':500
                                                          };

                                                          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('container21'));

                                                          chart.draw(data, options);
                                                          chart.setSelection([{row: 38, column: 1}]);

                                                        }
                                                $('#modalReport1').modal('show');

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }); 
}
```

while clicking on link that loads assetReport() for the second time, my charts appears with no legend text.

Comment: this happens when the chart is drawn in a hidden container, show the container first, then draw the chart, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613423/5090771) for an example -- also `google.charts.load` only needs to be called once per page load, not each time you need to draw a chart. `google.charts.load` can also be used in place of `$(document).ready`