# Google Charts: Hide chart without losing vAxis annotation

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, hide

When i create 2 charts on my page i get perfect results, when i try to hide one of the charts when page loads and show it on a click, the annotation of vAxis disappears.

I tried jQuery, CSS in stylesheet and inline display:none, style="display:none", it always loses annotation of vAxis. 
I tried to specify vAxis format: 'currency' in options, nothing helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/crapomat/xguo8yfn/2/

```
      $('#chart_week').hide();
```

Scroll down the JavaScript window all the way to the bottom to find the line, it makes the annotation disappear. idk why. 
Click on "Woche", that's german for "week".

I want to have annotations on both charts. If you comment out the .hide() and reload page, the annotations show, but they disappear when i .hide() the #chart_week.

Sorry about the monster fiddle :(

thx for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens when the chart is drawn in a hidden container.
when the container is hidden,
the chart cannot properly calculate the size of the chart elements.

the solution is to wait until the container is shown,
before drawing the chart.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawIntraday);

function drawIntraday() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['time', 'ask', 'bid'],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,01), 19.045000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,04), 19.045000, 19.005000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,07), 19.045000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,10), 19.045000, 19.005000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,13), 19.045000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,16), 19.045000, 19.005000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,19), 19.045000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,22), 19.045000, 19.005000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,25), 19.045000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,28), 19.045000, 19.005000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,31), 19.050000, 19.005000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,34), 19.050000, 19.015000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,37), 19.050000, 19.015000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,40), 19.050000, 19.015000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,43), 19.050000, 19.015000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,46), 19.025000, 19.015000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,49), 19.050000, 19.015000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,52), 19.050000, 19.015000],
    [new Date(2019,4,10,08,55), 19.095000, 19.015000], [new Date(2019,4,10,08,58), 19.095000, 19.005000],
  ]);

  var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
  });

  date_formatter.format(data, 0);

  var options = {
    width: 360,
    height: 400,
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      format: 'HH:mm',
      gridlines: {count: 3}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_intraday'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawWeek() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['time', 'ask', 'bid'],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,02), 21.140000, 21.080000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,04), 21.140000, 21.080000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,07), 20.850000, 20.750000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,10), 20.850000, 20.750000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,13), 20.900000, 20.810000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,16), 20.850000, 20.760000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,19), 20.850000, 20.760000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,22), 20.850000, 20.780000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,25), 20.850000, 20.780000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,28), 20.850000, 20.780000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,31), 20.760000, 20.750000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,34), 20.770000, 20.750000],
    [new Date(2019,4,06,08,37), 20.770000, 20.720000], [new Date(2019,4,06,08,40), 20.770000, 20.710000],
  ]);

  var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
  });

  date_formatter.format(data, 0);
  var options = {
    width: 360,
    height: 400,
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
      gridlines: {count: 3}
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'currency'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_week'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

$('#aintra').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#chart_week').hide();
  $('#chart_intraday').show();
});

$('#aweek').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#chart_intraday').hide();
  $('#chart_week').show();
  drawWeek();
});
```

```css
#chartmenu nav ul li { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chartmenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="aintra"  class="chartlink">Intraday</a></li>
      <li><a id="aweek"   class="chartlink">Woche</a></li>
      <li><a id="amonth"  class="chartlink">Monat</a></li>
      <li><a id="a3month" class="chartlink">3 Monate</a></li>
      <li><a id="a6month" class="chartlink">6 Monate</a></li>
      <li><a id="a1year"  class="chartlink">Jahr</a></li>
      <li><a id="a3year"  class="chartlink">3 Jahre</a></li>
      <li><a id="a10year" class="chartlink">10 Jahre</a></li>
      <li><a id="amax"    class="chartlink">Max</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="charts">
  <div id="intra"><div id="chart_intraday"></div></div>
  <div id="week"><div id="chart_week"></div></div>
  <div id="month"></div>
  <div id="threemonth"></div>
  <div id="sixmonth"></div>
  <div id="oneyear"></div>
  <div id="threeyears"></div>
  <div id="tenyears"></div>
</div>
```

---

full fiddle with all the data...

https://jsfiddle.net/rgm8yhuk/

Comment: hope this helps, here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613032/google-chart-legends-overlapping-text/41613423#41613423)...

Comment: Thanks, this helps

Comment: One more question: Is there any way to circumvent the function call when the link is clicked? On a mobile device it takes quite some time every time i click on the #amonth (that's an other fiddle, I didn't include drawMonth())

Comment: yes, use a boolean variable to determine if the chart has been drawn yet...