# Why Google charts' width not working when change display from none to block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I create a Google charts' with width=100%:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["test", "val", { role: "style" } ],
    ["test", 21.45, "color: red"]
  ]);
  var options = {
          height: '300px',
          width: '100%'
          };
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view,options);
  }
</script>
<div id="columnchart_values"></div>
```

Then, I create the same charts with display=none beginning. and shows
   chart after click:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["test", "val", { role: "style" } ],
  ["test", 21.45, "color: red"]
    ]);
    var options = {
          width: '100%'
          };
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
    chart.draw(view,options);
    }
  function test() {
  document.getElementById("columnchart").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
<div onclick="javascript:test()"> click me </div>
<div id="columnchart" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display:none;"></div>
```

But it seems in the second method, Google charts' width style not working and only show the default width. Can anyone helps me? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are drawing chart but not display it and onClick event you just display it, what you can do is, draw your chart in onClient event and display, that will work perfect as shown by @Sergej.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redraw the chart with the options after changing the `display` to block;

Do the same on the `window`'s `resize` event, if you wish to.

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

{
  let data, options, view, chart;
  
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ["test", "val", {
        role: "style"
      }],
      ["test", 21.45, "color: red"]
    ]);
    options = {
      width: '100%'
    };
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }

  function test() {
    document.getElementById("columnchart").style.display = "block";
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('open-chart').addEventListener('click', test);
  window.addEventListener('resize', test)
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="open-chart" onclick="test()"> click me </div>
<div id="columnchart" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: this is correct, the chart should only be drawn when the container is visible, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613423/5090771) -- and -- google charts only needs to be loaded once per page load, you can draw as many charts, as many times as needed, afterwards. @Sergej 's comment is correct about calculation...

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript cannot calculate the width while the block have `display: none;`

So as the script cannot calculate the width, it takes default `400px` width.

To fix this issue you have several options:

1) do not use `display: none`, but use: `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden`

2) draw the chart when the block becomes visible (`display: block`), so the calculation will be possible.

If you call draw graph just before displaying the element, then it works good.
It is because, the graph is actually drawn, when the block is already having `display: block`, since the graph is drawn asynchronously, using the callback.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawGraph() {

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["test", "val", { role: "style" } ],
  ["test", 21.45, "color: red"]
    ]);
    var options = {
          width: '100%'
          };
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
    chart.draw(view,options);
    }
}
  function test() {
  drawGraph();
  document.getElementById("columnchart").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
<div onclick="javascript:test()"> click me </div>
<div id="columnchart" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: This will reload the whole google resources, when you click. It's would only be necessary to recall the `chart.draw()` method with the same arguments

Comment: yes, but I just gave an idea, optimization is another part.

Comment: Without drawing chart once again he can just draw chart one time just moving  google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']}); and google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); to test() function.

Answer (score 0):

The width of your div `#columnchart` is `100%` i.e full viewport
but as you can see the graph is not of full width i.e because
the chart created by google is of fixed width
If you debug you will see this
[image]

you can see the width is `400px`

// Set chart options

```
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                     'width':400,
                     'height':300};
chart.draw('', options);
```

Comment: thanks,but I have edit and add chart options in my second field,it still not working

Comment: Try setting it without %. It will accept numbers only like 400, 800

Comment: thanks,but options can accept % as I change in my first code field ~

Answer (score 0):

Try something like checking the length of data and then assign 0 values before and after the .addrow function if the data has only one row because usually groupWidth doesn reflect if chart has only one column. See below:

```
 if (yourdatatable.length == 1) {
        data.addRow(['', 0, '#fa1150', '']);       
    }
    for (i = 1; i < yourdatatable.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([yourdatatable[i]['Name'], yourdatatable[i]['Percentage'], 
        '#fa1150', yourdatatable[i]['Percentage'].toString()]);       
    }
    if (yourdatatable.length == 1) {
        data.addRow(['', 0, '#fa1150', '']);       
    }
```